# actix-web で起動したサーバーに別の端末からアクセスできない

Tags: network, rust

actix-web で起動したサーバーに同じローカルネットワーク内の別の端末からアクセスしたいのですが、curlすると以下のようになってしまいます。
(同じ端末からはアクセスできます)

```
curl http://192.168.0.9:8080
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.0.9 port 8080: Connection refused
```

main.rs 抜粋

```rust
use std::fs;
use actix_web::{ web, App, HttpResponse, HttpServer, Responder};
use actix_files;
use tera::{Tera, Context};
use natord;

// ...省略...

#[actix_rt::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let tera = Tera::new("templates/**/*").unwrap();

    HttpServer::new(move || {
        App::new()
            .app_data(web::Data::new(tera.clone()))
            .route("/", web::get().to(index))
            .service(actix_files::Files::new("/js", "static/js").show_files_listing())
            .service(actix_files::Files::new("/css", "static/css").show_files_listing())
    })
    .bind(("127.0.0.1", 8080))?
    .bind(("127.0.1.1", 8080))?
    .bind(("<hostname>.local", 8080))?
    .run()
    .await
}
```

#### 環境

- Archlinux 6.3.1-arch2-1
- rustc 1.69.0 (84c898d65 2023-04-16) (Arch Linux rust 1:1.69.0-3)
- actix-http v3.3.1
- actix-web v4.3.1

どう変更すればよいでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `127.0.0.1` ではなく、  `192.168.0.9` にbindする必要があるのではないでしょうか？

Comment: 他者のIPアドレスにはbindできないので `0.0.0.0` かなと思います

Comment: .bind(("0.0.0.0", 8080))? でうまくいきました。
また、コメント欄に気づかず返信が遅れてすみませんでした。
お二人ともありがとうございました。

Comment: 自分のローカルIP `192.168.1.xxx` で動いたのでbindできないということはないはずですが、コードに埋め込む形なら明らかに `0.0.0.0` がベターでしたね。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

コメントで回答していただいた方々のお陰で解決しました。

- > 127.0.0.1 ではなく、 192.168.0.9 にbindする必要があるのではないでしょうか？ – eduidl
- > 他者のIPアドレスにはbindできないので 0.0.0.0 かなと思います – κeen

ありがとうございます。

```
use std::fs;
use actix_web::{ web, App, HttpResponse, HttpServer, Responder};
use actix_files;
use tera::{Tera, Context};
use natord;

// ...省略...

#[actix_rt::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let tera = Tera::new("templates/**/*").unwrap();

    HttpServer::new(move || {
        App::new()
            .app_data(web::Data::new(tera.clone()))
            .route("/", web::get().to(index))
            .service(actix_files::Files::new("/js", "static/js").show_files_listing())
            .service(actix_files::Files::new("/css", "static/css").show_files_listing())
    })
    .bind(("0.0.0.0", 8080))?
    .run()
    .await
}
```

##### 参考になりそうなURL

- [127.0.0.1とlocalhostと0.0.0.0の違い - Qiita](https://qiita.com/1ain2/items/194a9372798eaef6c5ab)